# How to set properly android studio Gradle versions in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle

I want to know how to choose Gradle versions in flutter project? Here is `android\build.gradle` file which has Gradle version `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'` and there is a `android\gradle\gradle-wrapper.properties` file which has this line `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip` 
What is the difference between these two Gradle versions?
How should I choose the right version for Flutter in android studio?
Is there a way like command to update these versions automatically?

[image]

**android\build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'       // <======= Kotlin version
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'  //<======= Here
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

**android\gradle\gradle-wrapper.properties**

[image]

```
    #Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```